# Laravel: return data from server without redirect

Tags: ajax, laravel, payment-gateway, applepay

What I'm trying to do is call function form server and validate data in javascript function but the return statement from server make redirect before `response.complete("success")`

```
button.onclick = async function handlePurchase() {
  const payment = new PaymentRequest(methods, details, options);
  try {
    const response = await payment.show();
    // Call server logic here and validate response if OK continue 
    // But server response redirect here so code not completed
    $('#checkout-form').submit();
    $.ajax({
    url: '{{route("apple-pay")}}',
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#checkout-form').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          console.log('data :>> ', data);
      }
    });  
    await response.complete("success");
    // redirect to success page
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Uh oh, something bad happened", err.message);
  }
}
```

Server function:

```
    public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $merchant_id = env('CREDIMAX_MERCHANT_ID');
        $password = env('CREDIMAX_INTEGRATION_PASSWORD');

        $response = Http::withBasicAuth('merchant.'.$merchant_id, $password)->put
        ('https://example.com/api/rest/merchant/'.$merchant_id.'/order/1530/transaction/1', $data);

        return $respone->json();

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seperate the request you are making to the third party app and the response you are sending back to you ajax call. This is how I mean:

```php
public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $merchant_id = env('CREDIMAX_MERCHANT_ID');
        $password = env('CREDIMAX_INTEGRATION_PASSWORD');

        $response = Http::withBasicAuth('merchant.'.$merchant_id, $password)->put
        ('https://example.com/api/rest/merchant/'.$merchant_id.'/order/1530/transaction/1', $data);

        return response()->json([
          'success' => $response->ok() ? 1 : 0,
          ...
        ]);

     }
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is  $('#checkout-form').submit(); make redirect so is there anyway to submit form without redirect because there are data needed from laravel session

Comment: Building on MHD_SY can you add a preventDefault like so:   $('#checkout-form').on('submit',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
   });

Answer (score 0):

Check the last line in the controller it says "return $respone->json();" and should be "return $response->json();" -- missing the "s" in response.

Comment: It's just typo mistake